# Run methods thats name was passed as a string

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my WPF MVVM project I have to execute some 10 methods in one go without passing individual name one by one. Lets say I can do this for a single method call:

```
CallStaticMethod("MainApplication.Test", "Test1");
```

its body:

```
public static void CallStaticMethod(string typeName, string methodName)
{
    var type = Type.GetType(typeName);

    if (type != null)
    {
        var method = type.GetMethod(methodName);

        if (method != null)
        {
            method.Invoke(null, null);
        }
    }
}

public static class Test
{
    public static void Test1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test invoked");
    }
}
```

But I have the requirement:

```
public static class Test
{
    public static void Test1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test invoked");
    }

    public static void Test2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test invoked");
    }

    public static void Test3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test invoked");
    }

    public static void CallAllTestMethod()
   {
       Test1();
       Test2();
       Test3();
   }
}
```

Now I want to call this `CallAllTestMethod()` and also want to know which method (`Test1`,`Test2` or `Test3`) is currently being processed. Any thought on this?

Comment: Your `CallStaticMethod` already does what the question title requests - to invoke by name. Is the question here "how to find all the methods available?".... or: what *is* the question, exactly?

Comment: Un clear. are you looking for `type.GetMethods()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You kind of try to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803/how-do-i-intercept-a-method-call-in-c). As stated in that thread it's pretty difficult to do so.

Why don't you create an event which gets fired by each of the test methods? You can then [register to those events using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121441/addeventhandler-using-reflection).

Comment: you can use a list of delegates:

var actions = new List<Action<string[]>>();
actions.Add(this.GetReports);
actions.Add(this.GetUsers);
actions.Add(this.GetEmployees);

And calling them is easy:

foreach (var action in actions)
{
    action(new[] { "All" });
}



var actions = new List<Action>();
actions.Add(() => this.GetReports(new[] { "Foo" }));
actions.Add(() => this.GetUsers(new[] { "Bar" }));
// etc

foreach (var action in actions)
{
    action();
}

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list of delegates: var actions = new List>(); actions.Add(this.GetReports); actions.Add(this.GetUsers); actions.Add(this.GetEmployees); And calling them is easy: foreach (var action in actions) { action(new[] { "All" }); } var actions = new List(); actions.Add(() => this.GetReports(new[] { "Foo" })); actions.Add(() => this.GetUsers(new[] { "Bar" })); // etc foreach (var action in actions) { action(); }